# fromphone, fromemail and fromurl

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

I am using koma-script `scrlttr2` to write a letter.

```
\documentclass[12pt,foldmarks=true,foldmarks=blmtP,
fromalign=right,fromrule=aftername,
fromphone,fromemail,fromurl,subject=centered, parskip=full, 
version=last]{scrlttr2}
```

On the `fromalign`, I have `fromphone`, `fromemail`, and `fromurl`. In front of the `fromurl` value, text 'url' is printed. So, I have two questions:

1. How can I replace 'url' text in front of `fromurl` value with 'Website'?
2. `frommobilephone` is giving me error message, is `frommobilephone`
   not valid?

Answer (score 4):

1. You can use `\setkomavar{urlseparator}[Webseite]{:~}` or if you are loading `babel` with your language option - I guess it is `ngerman` - `\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\wwwname}{Webseite}`.

   2. `frommobilephone` works for me.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,foldmarks=true,foldmarks=blmtP, fromalign=right,fromrule=aftername, fromphone,fromemail,fromurl,subject=centered, parskip=full, version=last,
frommobilephone 
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Vorname Name} 
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Absenderadresse} 
\setkomavar{fromphone}{yyyy} 
\setkomavar{fromemail}{aaa@bbb.cc} 
\setkomavar{fromurl}{www.dddd.ee}
\setkomavar{frommobilephone}{xxxx}

%\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\wwwname}{Webseite}
\setkomavar{urlseparator}[Webseite]{:~}

\begin{document} 
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject} 
\begin{letter}{Empfängeradresse} 
\opening{Hallo} 
Text
\closing{Viele Grüße} 
\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, esdd, for this.  As for 'frommobilephone', I won't bother at this stage.